# Import a worksheet from another workbook (#2) to current workbook (#1)

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code that is opening a window in which I can select a the excel workbook (#2) I want to copy and import the worksheet from. 
The Code is then checking whether the wanted worksheet (named "Guidance") exists in the opened workbook (#2).If so it should be copied and pasted into the current workbook (#1).
After pasting the worksheet the workbook (#2) should be closed again.

So far the code does what I want it to do, as it opens the window and lets me select the wanted worksheet (named "Guidance") but I have the bug (not sure if the translation is correct)

> "Runtime error '9': index out of range"

where the worksheet is supposed to be copied and pasted.

Any help on that would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
 Private Function SheetExists(sWSName As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean

 If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    Set InWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
 End If

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 On Error Resume Next
 Set ws = Worksheets(sWSName)
 If Not ws Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True

 On Error GoTo 0

 End Function


 Sub GuidanceImportieren()


 Dim sImportFile As String, sFile As String
 Dim sThisWB As Workbook
 Dim vFilename As Variant

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 Set sThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
 sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Workbooks, 
 *xls; *xlsx; *xlsm")

 If sImportFile = "False" Then
 MsgBox ("No File Selected")
 Exit Sub

 Else
 vFilename = Split(sImportFile, "|")
 sFile = vFilename(UBound(vFilename))
 Application.Workbooks.Open (sImportFile)

 Set wbWB = Workbooks("sImportFile")
 With wbWB
 If SheetExists("Guidance") Then
 Set wsSht = .Sheets("Guidance")
 wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisWB.Sheets("Guidance")
 Else
 MsgBox ("No worksheet named Guidance")
 End If

 wbWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
 End With
 End If

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note: You should add either a `On Error GoTo 0` or `Err.Clear` right before `End Function` otherwise `Err` will not be cleared in case a sheet does not exist.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for the hint!

Comment: Does sThisWB already have a sheet named "Guidance"? Because the Before argument used in Copy method uses an existing sheet as reference, so if the sheet doesn't exist yet it can't be referenced

Comment: Oh I actually deleted the sheets called "Guidance" with a previous code that checks, whether it exists and deletes it if it does.

Comment: @HenriquePessoa how can I  just insert it to the beginning current workbook?

Comment: Maybe just with before:=sThisWB.Sheets(1) ?

Comment: Yes, I think that should work

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here

```
Set wbWB = Worksheets("Guidance") '<-- this should be a workbook not a worksheet?
With wbWB '<-- this with is useless until …
    If SheetExists("Guidance") Then
        Set wsSht = .Sheets("Guidance") '<-- … until Sheets here starts with a dot
        wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisWB.Sheets("Guidance") 'if the error is here then there is no sheet "Guidance" in sThisWB
    Else
        MsgBox ("No worksheet named Guidance")
    End If
    wbWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
```

Also note that `SheetExists("Guidance")` does not check in a specific workbook (which may fail). I recommend to extend the function to:

```
Private Function SheetExists(WorksheetName As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        Set InWorkbook = ThisWorkbook 'fallback if not set
    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = InWorkbook.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    SheetExists = Not ws Is Nothing
    On Error Goto 0 'necessary because the Err.Number will not be cleared on End Function
End Function
```

So you can test if a worksheet exists in a specific workbook like

```
SheetExists("Guidance", sThisWB)
SheetExists("Guidance", wbWB)
```

---

```
Sub GuidanceImportieren()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim sImportFile As String
    sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *xls; *xlsx; *xlsm")

    If sImportFile = False Then 'false should not be "false"
        MsgBox "No File Selected"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim vFilename As Variant
        vFilename = Split(sImportFile, "|")

        Dim sFile As String
        sFile = vFilename(UBound(vFilename))

        Dim ImportWorkbook As Workbook
        Set ImportWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(sImportFile)

        If SheetExists("Guidance", ImportWorkbook) Then
            ImportWorkbook.Sheets("Guidance").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Guidance")
            'you might need to change it into something like this:
        Else
            MsgBox "No worksheet named Guidance"
        End If

        ImportWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I think the first line should be a workbook and I also added the "." in front of Sheets in the 4th line.

Comment: In the worksheet that I selected in the window that opened previously there is a sheet called "Guidance", so I don't understand why it doesn't find it..

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn See my edit. Maybe you check in the wrong workbook for existence of the sheet.

Comment: Don't  I check in the worksheet that I just opened by defining sFile as the current workbook two lines above?

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn not necessarily. I won't rely on that. Never let Excel guess which workbook you mean. Always specify workbook and worksheet exactly, otherwise you never know for sure what happens.

Comment: Ok now I get the bug "Insufficiently defined reference" For the

Comment: If SheetExists("Guidance") Then
            Set wsSht = .Sheets("Guidance") '<-- … until Sheets 
    here starts with a dot
            wsSht.Copy Before:=sThisWB.Sheets("Guidance") 'if 
    the error is here then there is no sheet "Guidance" in 
    sThisWB
        Else

Comment: the line where it says .sheets

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn Please edit the code in your original question. Comments  with code are not readable. All your question part needs to be in the original question.

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn Have a look to my edit. Note that `ImportWorkbook.Sheets("Guidance").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Guidance")` might not work because if there is already a sheet "Guidance" you cannot add another one with the same name. So you might need to rename it into something else. • Also use meaningful variable names like `ImportWorkbook` instead of `wbWb` this makes your code much easier to maintain and more human readable.